# Open Broadcaster Software compressing video size

Tags: recording, obs

Anyone knows what are the optimal settings for Video Recording using Open Broadcaster Software? Keeping acceptable 720p or 1080p quality but not too big of a file. I've tried recording a 27 minute video with these settings:

Quality Balance: 10
Audio Encoding Codec: AAC
1920 * 1080 Resolution
30 FPS
Custom x264 Encoder settings with crf=0 vbv-maxrate=0 vbv-bufsize=0

And it turned into a 34GB file. Pretty ridiculous.

Comment: Your settings are probably too high quality to ever have a low file size. Drop the quality, turn the custom encoder settings back to the defaults, and record a 1 minute video. See what the file size is and how good it looks. *Then* tweak, and repeat. Do that until you find settings that give a file size/quality combination *you* find acceptable, because no-one else can tell you what will look good to you. There is no such thing as optimal, since higher quality means bigger files and you just have to decide what balance suit you.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is *a bit late* but for people googling (like me), crf=0 means lossless. Use 15-20.